# Flash automatically finds curve intersection points. Can I use that code like I use curveTo in actionscript?

Tags: actionscript-3, path, intersection, intersect, curves

Or do I have to get down and dirty with the math and do the spline intersection math myself? I know the basic math for Quadratic b-splines.

I'm trying to make procedural randomly generated Celtic knot-work that animates itself. I'm inspired by the book of Kells original book -and the animation of the same name. This means at best it will be seriously complicated - lots of curves animating fast. I'm going for generative -responsive to the user- Celtic knots of the highest possible complexity.... that may mean only 12 points animating randomly and in response to mouse movements but... I'd love hundreds or tens of thousands... some day.

Developing a moving random curvy double lined loop scribble was easy. I like the look of the curves made from 12 to 14 random points. Now I want to weave it over under over under.  To do that -- I need to find the intersections of lots of random curves quickly for each frame.  When I draw curves in Flash in the -not object- drawing mode... Flash does intersections and generates points automatically for me.

Questions:
-Is there an equivalent intersection class/method/function in Actionscript 3.0 to the intersections so easily done in the flash drawing interface?

-How much of what you do in Flash as an artist has cool classes like curveTo in Actionscript 3.0?

-Can I see the source code for curveTo?

-Can I extend the curveTo to do what I want?

-I have been reading and re-reading the reference and how to extend classes... that I made.  But how to I learn how to extend curveTo ... or Path classes... can I?

Answer (score 0):

Would this be something that you are looking for:
http://actionsnippet.com/?p=965

See a demo here: http://www.actionsnippet.com/swfs/bezier_intersect.html